# Pass a parameter to my .net script

Tags: .net, umbraco

OK, I am fairly new to Umbraco and I am tying to figure some stuff out. I wrote a simple .net script:

```
@{string listString = Model.MyList;}

@{string[] listItems = listString.Split(':');}

<ul class="BulletedList PadBottom PadTop">
@foreach (string item in listItems)
{
    <li><span>@item</span></li>;
}
</ul>
```

I have a custom field in my content section, I would like the contents of this field to be placed into the macro script from the template instead of the Model.MyList value, how do I do that?

Also is this a best practice/workflow for what I am trying to accomplish?

How do I write a variable in the script to access one passed in through a macro tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the anser to my own queston, so I'll put it here for anyone else who might be looking for the same thing.

To pass a content field value to a macro, you need to use the Bracket syntax, [#propertyAlias]. So for example if I have a page field custom property called "myCustomProperty" I can simply insert it into the macro like so:

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="MyMacro" pageValue="[#myCustomProperty]" />
```

more info on this can be found here: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/templates/umbracomacro-element/macro-parameters/advanced-macro-parameter-syntax

This will pass the value of the page field to your macro. To see it in the macro script (.net script) you will need to reference it via the Parameter object. for example:

```
@{string myString = Parameter.fieldValue;}
```

so example script might look like the following:

```
@{string myString = Parameter.fieldValue;}

@{string[] listItems = myString.Split(':');}

<ul class="BulletedList PadBottom PadTop">
@foreach (string item in listItems)
{
    <li><span>@item</span></li>;
}
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.